# is this code using UIActivityIndicatorView flawed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Is this code using UIActivityIndicatorView flawed?   It appears that I don't actually get to see the indicator/spinner at all here, so is this because the view isn't drawn until the who viewDidLoad completes?

Is the only way around this to do the viewDidLoad custom work (e.g. data updates) on a separate thread?  (I was hoping in this case for an easier single-thread operation).  Is there a way to force the view to refresh after the "startAnimating" line perhaps prior to the data loading commencment?

Code from UITableViewController implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Wait indicator - Start
    self.waitView = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];
    self.waitView.hidesWhenStopped = true;
    [self.view addSubview: self.waitView];

    // Load data into tableview
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 5.0];   // Test code to simulate

    [self.waitView stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the size and origin of the UIActivityIndicatorView.

Comment: what is "load data into tableview"? when is `stopAnimating` called?

Comment: sorry - will update to the correct code re this - try that

Comment: re - size and origin of the UIActivityIndicatorView - well initially when I had startAnimating instead of stopAnimating (which I fixed) I could see the activity indicator in the top left, so I should be able to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also call startAnimating. Sleeping is not a good idea. I would prefer the `performSelector`-methods which starts a not recurring NSTimer under the hood.

Try this:

```
-(void) doStuff:(id)aSender
{
    [self.waitView stopAnimating];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(doStuff:) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

in addtion: also set the frame- or bounds-property of the ActivityIndicatorView somewhere like sosborn said in his comment

Comment: I was just using sleep to simulate a heavy table data update code - so just to clarify are you suggesting that sleep isn't a good choice for emulating by update logic once it's in place?  That is I was keen in this thread to understand what is possible in a "single threaded" so to speak operation...just checking you understood this?

Comment: ah, ok, I just thought that you want to simulate a asynchronous task. Then sleeping is the right testing-behaviour. But if your db-stuff will take a long time then you should outsource the db-stuff. I assume that your code will run in the MainThread. The view wont update if the MainThread is doing some db-work and your activity-indicator wont be displayed.

Comment: got it - interesting that it seems all the code in viewDidLoad completes (i.e. including code after the perform selector line) prior to seeing the "doStuff" method commencing - I hadn't assumed this is how things work

Comment: the `performSelector:afterDelay:` starts an NSTimer inside and returns immediately. The MainLoop is then able to run without to be disturbed. If the delay is over the selector will be called at the end of the current MainLoop. So the delay will be always >= 5 seconds not exactly 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer from Thomas should work as it is, I will add a little explanation as to why not use sleep as you have done it.

All the UI processing on iPhone (and most of OSs as well) is being done in only one thread - the main thread, the thread that executes the so called run loop. If you stop that thread the UI will stop, nothing will be drawn.

Putting sleep into viewDidLoad, which runs in the main thread, will do just that - stop UI from doing anything. So because immediately after wakeup you've called  `[self.waitView stopAnimating]` and the activityview should hide when not animating, you can't see it at all - you just didn't give it any time to show.

Thomas used a NSTimer to call stopAnimating after 5 seconds - now this lets the main thread to execute code before stopping animation and hiding waitView and this will work for your test.

Better yet you just let it animate without any timer and use a delegate patter to be informed by the tableView loading code after the data has been loaded, then stop animating. You don't know how long loading of data will last, so it's better to wait until it's finished than stop animating after any specific time.

Oh well, and the size and position, makes sense, but for testing it doesn't matter and is not the cause of not seeing it - if not specified it will be added at 0,0 and have a default size so you will see it anyway.

Comment: @Thomasz - thanks - so just check (per my comment for Thomas) you are saying then that the "sleep" function doesn't emulate the same thing as a delay of 5 seconds of my updated logic?  (i.e. is there a difference between 5 seconds of active update logic being run, as opposed to sleeping for 5 seconds) - I think this is what you're saying but just double checking

Comment: Not quite: if done in background like using timer than it could be okay as means to see what happens on the UI, it kind of emulates data loading pause. In the real life you wouldn't do that because of unknown duration of data loading and use notification to turn activityview off. So actually you might as well test using the right scenario: start animating on viewDidLoad, call data loading code, there put a timer for 5s and on timer trigger send notification to your controller so that it turns off activityView. This way your controller has the proper logic.

Comment: And: regardless of how you emulate you should never put main thread to sleep because you otherwise see nothing on the UI.